# SQL Insert error [SQLSate[4200]

Tags: sql, csv, magento2.3.3, admin-user

We are using an extension called Mass Product Import & Update. My colleague gets SQL error when he is trying to upload a CSV file to add/update products/group products in this extension, but I have no issues, I can use the same CSV file as him and that goes through successfully.

If he logs in with my credentials he is able to upload the CSV file but when he logs back to his profile he gets the error again.

Comment: What type of error, Please check  with php configuration

Comment: Thank you for your reply.

I have edited the post with the whole error message.

Answer (score 0):

A quick workaround, maybe not the best solution.

I just deleted the user and created it again and he was able to run the profile on the Mass Product Import & Update again.

Answer (score 0):

We found out the source of this, since he had NO as language when navigating through the admin. The Module did not support that and that's why got the error message. when he change to English there where no issue to the uploads anymore.